# How to use reserved names as variable in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Is there any way to use the reserved names as a variable?

For example:

```
class MyColors {
    static Color get default {
       return Colors.blue;
    }
}
```

So that I can use it as `MyColors.default`.

Comment: The whole point about these names being reserved is that you cannot use them

Comment: Correct @RémiRousselet, but in other languages have some hack to do that. eg. Swift has `backtick to escape the reserved names. So I was looking for something like the same.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, this is not yet available in Dart.  There is a somewhat-active open issue regarding it, though.  So, hopefully it'll be supported eventually.

#271 Escaped reserved words
https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/271